# Suggestions on Saving Poses in Nav2 to Databases

Tags: ros-humble, nav2

I need some suggestions on how to save poses / locations of the robot in Nav2. Is it better to use some kind of databases like sqlite or create a specific action servers to communicate with a centralized db. Thank you

Comment: I know ‘it depends’ isn’t a satesfying answer, but you haven’t given us much detail to go on about your application, its maturity, and what you’re aiming to store (and any relationships).

Comment: It all boils down to what you want to achieve with the robot. If the use case is relatively trivial, i.e., you just need to store the poses of some picking/docking stations, a database would certainly be overkill. You can get by with creating and storing the info in a json/yaml file, and load the poses on startup into dictionaries.

A database would make more sense in case you'd like to aggregate multiple poses/make them available for a fleet of robots maybe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.